# Android Scrollview doesn't scroll when keyboard appears onClick of EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview

I've been through n number of solutions for this problem and tried them all but nothing helped. 
I have an `EditText` and `onClick` of it, a custom keyboard appears but the `EditText` doesn't comes up above the keyboard.

I have tried putting:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

in my Manifest file.
I read somewhere that its a bug and it does not work in FULLSCREEN mode so I removed fullscreen mode from my manifest. Again didn't work. 
Please help scrolling my EditText up :D

P.S: Please don't answer for android's default keyboard. I am using my own custom keyboard.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

Answer (score 1):

In scrollView use the following code:

```
    in XML:

    android:fillViewport="true"
```

OR

```
   in Java:
    setFillViewport(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a **translate animation**, to move the Edit-text or the entire view above the keyboard along with the **Y-axis**.

As you are using a custom keyboard,no other way seems to be possible.